# How can I set DataTables row callbacks in a Shiny R application?

Tags: javascript, r, datatables, shiny

In rCharts, one can set JS callbacks of DataTables using a special string notation: `#! function(par) {...} !#`. For example, let's look into the following R code:

```r
  #JS callback to truncate long strings in table cells and add a tooltip
  callback = "#! 
  function (nRow) {
        $('td', nRow).each(function (index) {
            var maxChars = 80;
                var unfilteredText = $(this).text();
                if (unfilteredText.length > maxChars && maxChars > 3) {
                    $(this).attr('title', unfilteredText);
                    $(this).html(unfilteredText.substring(0, maxChars-4) + '...');
                }
        });
        return nRow;
    } !#"

  result <- dTable(df, aaSorting = list(c(5, "desc")), sPaginationType="full_numbers",
               fnRowCallback=callback)
```

Is this possible in Shiny DataTables?

Comment: Have you tried embedding that code in a Shiny application?

Comment: It seems Shiny does not support JS callbacks yet. [Here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/pull/279#issuecomment-31264721) is a discussion about my question.

Comment: Shiny does support JS callbacks in DataTables now: http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderDataTable.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just stumbled across this question and was able to use the information here, along with help from section 4.5 of [this post](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html) to solve this problem. In order to get this to work, you would simply do the following:

```
library(DT)
long_strings = replicate(10, paste(sample(c(0:9, letters, LETTERS), 135, replace = TRUE), collapse = ""))
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:10, 
                  y = month.abb[1:10], 
                  z = long_strings, 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
DT::datatable(dat,
              options = list(
                rowCallback = JS("function(row, data) {",
                                 "  var max_chars = 80, full_text = data[3];",
                                 "    if (full_text.length > max_chars) {",
                                 "      $('td:eq(3)', row).attr('title', full_text);",
                                 "      $('td:eq(3)', row).html(full_text.substring(0, max_chars - 4) + '...');",
                                 "    }",
                                 "}")))
```

It's important to note that since we want this to operate on a per row basis, we use the `rowCallback` function **inside** of the `options` parameter. This is in contrast to the `callback` function that can be used on the entire table, which is its own parameter for `DT::datatable`.

Also take note of the fact that you don't have to call `.text()` or `.innerHTML` or anything of that sort on `data[3]`. The value that is returned is the text value of that cell.

Hopefully someone in the future stumbles across this and finds it beneficial.